# How to command google bigquery to show all row of time series data (don't omit row)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I use an easy command for showing sales volume by store by goods item and by month in google Big Query but there are omitted month as some items were not  bought. So, I would to know is there coding for all months. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5jQW.jpg)

Now I try to solve the problem by build time index and item_code and cross join with store but it must be massive row if I apply this with all item code.

```
SELECT bp_no,sales_month,sales_year,sum(report_qty) AS volume
FROM my_table 
WHERE sales_year between 2016 and 2017 and bp_no is not null and report_qty is not null 
GROUP BY bp_no,sales_month,sales_year
ORDER BY bp_no,sales_year, sales_month
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrnPa.jpg)

Comment: can post your query as well?

Comment: SELECT bp_no,sales_month,sales_year,sum(report_qty) as volume       
FROM my_table                                                                                          
where sales_year between 2016 and 2017 and bp_no is not null and report_qty is not null group by bp_no,sales_month,sales_year                   
order by bp_no,sales_year,sales_month

Comment: were you able to solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary mapping table using a `WITH` statement that will hold your metadata for `year`, `month`, `store`, and `item`. It is slightly bootstrapped, but it should return your expected result.

**QUERY**

```
WITH META AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      YEAR,
      MONTH,
      STORE,
      ITEM,
    FROM
     `project.dataset.your_table`,
     UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,12)) AS MONTH,
     UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2016,2017) AS YEAR
    ORDER BY 1,2
)

SELECT
   META.YEAR,
   META.MONTH,
   META.STORE,
   META.ITEM,
   SUM(DATA.QUANTITY)
FROM
  META 
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.your_table` AS DATA ON META.MONTH = DATA.MONTH 
                                                    AND META.YEAR = DATA.YEAR 
                                                    AND META.ITEM = DATA.ITEM 
                                                    AND META.STORE = DATA.STORE
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4
```

You can obviously modify the upper bound and lower bound in the `GENERATE_ARRAY` function on the year if you want to look at a different time span.

It also assumes your month are in the form 1,2,3,...,12 and that both `YEAR` and `MONTH` have an `int64` type. If not, you will have to `CAST` these filed to `INT64`.

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

- More information about [`GENERATE_ARRAY`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_array)
- More information about[`UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays-and-repeated-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  bp_no,
  sales_month,
  sales_year,
  SUM(IFNULL(report_qty, 0)) AS volume
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT bp_no FROM `project.dataset.my_table`),
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 12)) sales_month,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2016, 2017)) sales_year
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.my_table` 
USING(bp_no, sales_month, sales_year)
GROUP BY bp_no, sales_month, sales_year
```